# Have installed texlive but no tlmgr follows

Tags: texlive, installing

For example, when I enter

```
$ tlmgr update --self 
$
```

into the terminal, I get no message back, no error, nothing, just a new line; it looks like `tlmgr` does not install in my OS at all. However, I have followed the instruction about setting the path and add the following to the `.profile`

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/texlive/2022/bin/x86_64-linux
export INFOPATH=$INFOPATH:/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/doc/info
export MANPATH=$MANPATH:/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/doc/man
```

No sure what have gone wrong. Should I reinstall the texlive? Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: If you have logged out and logged back in again (so that your `.profile` has been sourced), try running `tlmgr --version`, you should get something - either a version number, or an error along the lines of `tlmgr: command not found`, which comes from the shell (if the command doesn't exist on the PATH).

Comment: Note that because you might by mistake install larex from the system, it is better to put the addition at the from instead of adding it at the end

Comment: It might also be an idea to add it to both `.profile`  and `.bashrc` then you just need to start a new terminal to test it

Comment: If an executable can't be found, the shell usually complains. But if it is found, the Unix style is not to complain about anything if there's nothing to complain about. You can check if it ran OK by entering ```echo $?```. Alternatively you can try ```tlmgr --help```.

Comment: @Ronald I tried the ```echo$?``` and it return ```0``` , which I suppose it means no error. @daleif I have also added the three addition to ```PATH``` in both ```.profile``` and ```.bashrc```, and still not work.  @enkorvaks I have sourced the ```.profile``` as ```source ~/.profile```, though it does not return any error, ```tlmgr``` is still missing from the system. On the other hand, other command such as ```tex```, ```latex```, etc work fine. I may have been better to reinstall the texlive and see what happens. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by reinstallation.

Comment: Please accept this answer do mark the question closed.